# Can a Google Oauth refresh token cover multiple urls?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have 3 sites running which all use the same credentials.json file and have the same Refresh token. Reason being is that all 3 sites are listed in the redirect URLs so I assumed they could inter-change.

All 3 sites have *different* access tokens which appear to have been issued about a month ago however all have a timeout of 3599. The problem I'm getting is that now none of the sites are able to re-generate the tokens and I end up getting `Invalid Grant - Bad request` . I have seen from elsewhere this can be where the Secret/ID are different but in my case they aren't.

Is there a scenario where you aren't allowed to use the same Oauth credentials across domains or where access tokens would become un-refreshable after a month using Google? Whilst I can manually run the refresh process, I'm keen to sort the underlying issue first!

I am using Google API Client through PHP and the follwing code to get the Client. This generates the error but if I amend the code and manually run `// Request authorization from the user` then it will generate new tokens that again can be copied to the various deployments and last about a month.

```
public function getClient(){

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(\Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_MODIFY);
    $client->setAuthConfig(APPPATH.'Config/Google/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    $tokenPath = APPPATH.'Config/Google/tokens.json';

    $token_json = file_get_contents($tokenPath);

    if (!empty($token_json)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode($token_json, true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }

        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }

        $ok = file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }

return $client;
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline: _"Note that there are limits on the number of refresh tokens that will be issued; one limit per client/user combination, and another per user across all clients. You should save refresh tokens in long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. If your application requests too many refresh tokens, it may run into these limits, in which case older refresh tokens will stop working."_ - wondering if that could have anything to do with it ...?

Comment: Thanks - I had read that but its only 1 token used in 3 places ??

Comment: But isn't the refresh token tied to one specific access token? Only the refresh token is send with the request, so to be able to return a fresh access token for a specific user, that must be the case, I think. But then I don't see how your "three different access tokens, but only one refresh token" setup works to begin with ...?